# Importing a local node C++ addon to a Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, node-modules

1. In a directory, I have this crazy simple Node.js addon that exposes a few C++ calls:

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "simple-addon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "gypfile": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node-gyp rebuild",
    "clean": "node-gyp clean"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/*.cpp",
    "src/*.hpp",
    "binding.gyp"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "node-gyp": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-addon-api": "^1.6.3"
  }
}
```

```js
// index.js
const simpleaddon = require('./build/Release/simple-addon.node');

module.exports = simpleaddon;
```

Building this with node-gyp goes fine, and as a sanity check I have been able to import and use it in a sample node app by doing `npm init`, `npm install ../simpleaddon` in a new directory.

2. In the Vue.js front-end app, created through vue-cli:

I was unable to simply import it (for reasons I still fail to understand completely, sorry), I had to use another loader: native-ext-loader. Else I would get `Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Configuring the loader:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
            .rule('native')
            .test(/\.node$/)
            .use('native-ext-loader')
            .loader('native-ext-loader')
    }
}
```

This did the trick but when I try to import in a component with `import simpleaddon from "simple-addon";`
I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot open /simple-addon.node: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dlopen' of undefined
    at Object.eval (simple-addon.node?5d7d:1)
    at eval (simple-addon.node:2)
    at Object../node_modules/simple-addon/build/Release/simple-addon.node (app.js:1663)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at eval (index.js?7d23:1)
    at Object../node_modules/simple-addon/index.js (app.js:1674)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/SimpleAddonComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:2)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're trying to load a C++ addon for frontend (browser) usage ?

Comment: Need to see your c++ code... I'm not seeing where you extern your c++ calls so that node.js can load them...

Comment: @Fluffy Did you manage to solve it? I'm dealing with exactly the same, expect I'm doing it in React

Comment: @johnyka, unfortunately no. But the intent was bad in the first place, I was trying to run C++ code from a frontend application, I ended up using socket.io to handle this pipe

Comment: Yes, I also found that this is not a good approach, in my use case webassembly is the right choice